# Rubymine -- Configuring remote SDK?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rubymine

I am unable to get a remote SDK to run from my client workstation. It complains that the remote SDK doesn't have rails installed.

Here is my environment:

Windows 8 Workstation:

- Rubymine

CentOS 7 Development Server:

- rvm (installed Ruby 2.1.2)
- /opt/learning_stuff (git repo with app in there)
- bundle install was ran

A few diagnostic commands yield these results:

```
# which ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby
# which rails
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/rails
```

How do I get rubymine to see the rails installation? Do I need to drop rvm and install from source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rubymine 7.1, I used my gem directory instead of the path to the ruby executable in the "Ruby interpreter path".  It found my gems for my project, and performed the sync.

Answer (score -1):

Not a solution to the actual problem, but what I ended up doing is just figuring out how to make the application work on both my windows localmachine and on my linux dev box. The benefit to this is that my application is now cross platform even though I don't need it to be.